# QGIS: Show label only when corresponding marker is displayed

Tags: qgis

I'm using rule-based symbology in QGIS to organize my data so that the markers of different categories of features can be turned on and off using the per-rule checkboxes in the layers window.

However, if I set up labels for a layer, they are always shown for all features, regardless whether the corresponding marker is displayed or not.

Is there any way to show a label only when the marker for the corresponding feature is displayed?

Comment: When I have rule based symbology and turn off one rule, the labels disappear as well. Did you also define rule-based labels? Can you provide more information, including screenshots? Otherwise, any answer is just guesswork.

Comment: Oops, I fooled myself by using invisible markers (instead of no symbols at all) for super-categories - and obviously, if the corresponding rules were ticked, I only saw the labels but no markers.
I think I'm going to delete my question since it probably won't be of much value to others.
Thank you for your help, that did put me onto the right track!

Comment: Add your comment as an answer - it could help others that do the same mistake. Sometime very obvious solutions are missed when you search the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, I fooled myself by using invisible markers (instead of no symbols at all) for super-categories - and obviously, if the corresponding rules were ticked, I only saw the labels but no markers.